# Run Serial inside Paralell Bash

Tags: linux, bash, while-loop, parallel-processing, wait

I have added to my explanation a bit. Conceptually, I am running a script that processes in a loop, calling shells that use the line content as an input parameter.(FYI: a kicks off an execution and b monitors that execution)

1. I am needing 1a and 1b to run first, in paralell for the first two $param
2. Next, 2a and 2b need to run in serial for $params when step 1 is complete
3. 3a and 3b will kick off once 2a and 2b are complete (irrelevant if serial or parallel)
4. Loop continues with next 2 lines from input .txt

I cant get it to process the second in serial, only all in parallel: What I need is the following

```
cat filename | while readline 
export param=$line
do
./script1a.sh "param" > process.lg && ./script2b.sh > monitor.log &&
##wait for processes to finish, running 2 in parallel in script1.sh
./script2a.sh "param" > process2.log && ./script2b.sh > minitor2.log &&
##run each of the 2 in serial for script2.sh
./script3a.sh && ./script3b.sh
```

I tried adding in wait, and tried an if statement containing script2a.sh and script2b.sh that would run in serial, but to no avail.

```
if ((++i % 2 ==0)) then wait fi
done
#only run two lines at a time, then cycle back through loop
```

How on earth can I get the script2.sh to run in serial as a result of script1 in parallel??

Comment: Some side notes: First, a math context is defined by `(( ))` -- **two** opening and closing parens.

Comment: Second, `.sh` extensions are appropriate for non-executable content intended to be sourced by a script, but not for commands (such as executable scripts with appropriate shebangs in place). Command names on UNIX don't have extensions -- after all, you run `ls`, not `ls.elf`, even if `ls` is in fact an ELF-format binary file on your distro. See https://www.talisman.org/~erlkonig/documents/commandname-extensions-considered-harmful.shtml for more discussion.

Comment: Third: `cat foo | something` is considerably less efficient than `something <foo`, and also has side effects around variable scope: This creates a subshell, and variables set inside the subshell disappear on its exit. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024 for more details.

Comment: BTW -- given here, you have `( )` not `(( ))`, despite saying otherwise in a comment on my deleted first answer. Perhaps you might want to double-check between what's given in the question and your actual code?

Comment: Previous related (but frankly unintelligible) question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29950596/parallel-processing-in-while-loop?noredirect=1#comment48027305_29950596

Comment: I still do not understand what you want the script to do. Can you write a script that is actually runable which does what you want, but in serial? And then point out which of these serial steps you want parallelized?

Comment: @oleTange I put my actual script here...what is difficult to explain is I am triggering a tool in Oracle Web Services to run a "model" based on the parameters in a txt file. These params are broken out by Model and Year (input.txt i,e, Model1,2015 /n Model1,2016 /n Model2,2015 /n Model2,2015...). I need 2 years of the same model to "Execute" in parallel, but the scripts that run after execution will error out in parallel, so they have to be serial. The scripts in serial "Transfer" the data so it can be loaded into the next model, which then goes through the loop until the end of the file

Comment: @OleTange please ask if you have any questions..I want to make this post useful if I can...I know my explanations have been sub-par

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not showing us how the lines you read from the file are being consumed.
If I understand your question correctly, you want to run `script1` on two lines of `filename`, each in parallel, and then serially run `script2` when both are done?

```
while read first; do
    echo "$first" | ./script1.sh &
    read second
    echo "$second" | ./script1.sh &
    wait
    script2.sh &    # optionally don't background here?
    script3.sh
done <filename &
```

The `while` loop contains two `read` statements, so each iteration reads two lines from `filename` and feeds each to a separate instance of `script1`.  Then we `wait` until they both are done before we run `script2`.  I background it so that `script3` can start while it runs, and background the whole `while` loop; but you probably don't actually need to background the entire job by default (development will be much easier if you write it as a regular foreground job, then when it works, background the whole thing when you start it if you need to).

I can think of a number of variations on this depending on how you actually want your data to flow; here is an update in response to your recently updated question.

```
export param  # is this really necessary?
while read param; do
    # First instance
    ./script1a.sh "$param" > process.lg  &&
    ./script2b.sh > monitor.log &

    # Second instance
    read param
    ./script2a.sh "$param" > process2.log && ./script2b.sh > minitor2.log &

    # Wait for both to finish
    wait

    ./script3a.sh && ./script3b.sh
done <filename
```

If this still doesn't help, maybe you should post a *third* question where you really actually explain what you want...

Comment: I was modifying and you answered...fast lol...if thats the case this may be the solution. I will build it into my script and give it a show. I was running in the background b/c I had the if (( ! % 2 ==0 ) then wait fi to kick off the next 2 processes when the first completed...in your method this doesnt seem necessary

Comment: See update near end, but the names of the scripts in your example are very obtuse. I have assumed 1a is the first producer, 2b is its monitor, and 2a/2b is the second pair. I didn't try to fix the typos or inconsistencies in the output file names.

Comment: what I put in here is just conceptual, just needed ideas to work with what I had, but the top approach ended up doing the trick! I just had to modify for my situation, but basically by reading in first and second I was able to run part in parallel and part in serial, 2 lines at a time. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Locking!

If you want to parallelize `script1` and `script3`, but need all invocations of `script2` to be serialized, continue to use:

```
./script1.sh && ./script2.sh && ./script3.sh &
```

...but modify `script2` to grab a lock before it does anything else:

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 3>.lock2
flock -x 3
# ... continue with script2's business here.
```

Note that you *must not* delete the `.lock2` file used here, at risk of allowing multiple processes to think they hold the lock concurrently.

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure what you mean with your question, but now I think you mean something like this in your inner loop:

```
(
   # run script1 and script2 in parallel
   script1 &
   s1pid=$!

   # start no more than one script2 using GNU Parallel as a mutex
   sem --fg script2

   # when they are both done...
   wait $s1pid

   # run script3
   script3

) &    # and do that lot in parallel with previous/next loop iteration
```

Comment: This doesn't meet the spec requiring no more than one instance of `script2` to run at a time. (My first answer didn't either, which is why I withdrew it; the question is indeed quite confusingly written).

Comment: Dare I add `GNU Parallel` running as a mutex in front of script2??? `sem script2` or will that offend?

Comment: Heh. That's actually a very appropriate use of the tool, as much distaste as I have from having had the misfortune to try to read its implementation.

Comment: (...though I'm very skeptical about some of the uses of `sem` given in its documentation; for instance, `sem --fg --id pod2html pod2html foo.pod > foo.html` doesn't block the shell executing that command from truncating `foo.html` *before* executing `sem` and starting to wait for the lock, making it ineffective for its stated purpose; in this case, `flock` would be a more appropriate tool, unless one wanted the complexity and efficiency hit of `sem sh -c '...'`).

Comment: I can't test this till tomorrow... it's late!

Comment: @MarkSetchell I am wanting to run the first 2 lines in parallel, not the first 2 scripts.....script 1 line1 in paralell with script 2 line 2, then script 2 line1 in serial with script 2 line 2

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question like:

You have a list of models. These models needs to be run. After they are run they have to be transferred. The simple solutions is:

```
run_model model1
transfer_result model1
run_model model2
transfer_result model2
```

But to make this go faster, we want to parallelize parts. Unfortunately `transfer_result` cannot be parallelized.

```
run_model model1
run_model model2
transfer_result model1
transfer_result model2
```

`model1` and `model2` are read from a text file. `run_model` can be run in parallel, and you would like 2 of those running in parallel. `transfer_result` can only be run one at a time, and you can only transfer a result when it has been computed.

This can be done like this:

```
cat models.txt | parallel -j2 'run_model {} && sem --id transfer transfer_model {}'
```

`run_model {} && sem --id transfer transfer_model {}` will run one model and if it succeeds transfer it. Transferring will only start if no other transfer is running.

`parallel -j2` will run two of the these jobs in parallel.

If transfer takes shorter than computing a model, then you should get no surprises: the transfers will at most be swapped with the next transfer. If transfer takes longer than running a model, you might see that the models are transferred completely out of order (e.g. you might see transfer of job 10 before transfer of job 2). But they *will* all be transferred eventually.

You can see the execution sequence exemplified with this:

```
seq 10 | parallel -uj2 'echo ran model {} && sem --id transfer "sleep .{};echo transferred {}"'
```

This solution is better than the `wait` based solution because you can run model3 while model1+2 is being transferred.

Answer (score 0):

@tripleee I put together the following if interested (note:I changed some variables for the post so sorry if there are inconsistencies anywhere...also the exports have their reasons. I think there is a better way than exporting, but for now it works)

```
cat input.txt | while read first; do
export step=${first//\"/}
export stepem=EM_${step//,/_}
export steptd=TD_${step//,/_}
export stepeg=EG_${step//,/_}
echo "$step" |  $directory"/ws_client.sh" processOptions  "$appName" "$step" "$layers" "$stages" "" "$stages" "$stages" FALSE > "$Folder""/""$stepem""_ProcessID.log" &&
$dir_model"/check_ status.sh" "$Folder" "$stepem" > "$Folder""/""$stepem""_Monitor.log" &
read second
export step2=${second//\"/}
export stepem2=ExecuteModel_${step2//,/_}
export steptd2=TransferData_${step2//,/_}
export stepeg2=ExecuteGeneology_${step2//,/_}
echo "$step2" |  $directory"/ws_client.sh" processOptions  "$appName" "$step2" "$layers" "$stages" "" "$stages" "$stages" FALSE > "$Folder""/""$stepem2""_ProcessID.log" && 
$dir _model"/check _status.sh" "$Folder" "$stepem2" > "$Folder""/""$stepem2""_Monitor.log" &
wait
$directory"/ws_client.sh" processOptions "$appName" "$step" "$layers" "" ""  "$stage_final" "" TRUE > "$appLogFolder""/""$steptd""_ProcessID.log" &&
$dir _model"/check_status.sh" "$Folder" "$steptd" > "$Folder""/""$steptd""_Monitor.log" &&
$directory"/ws_client.sh" processOptions "$appName" "$step2" "$layers" "" ""  "$stage_final" "" TRUE > "$appLogFolder""/""$steptd2""_ProcessID.log" &&
$dir _model"/check _status.sh" "$Folder" "$steptd2" > "$Folder""/""$steptd2""_Monitor.log" &
wait
$directory"/ws_client.sh" processPaths "$appName" "$step" "$layers" "$genPath_01" > "$appLogFolder""/""$stepeg""_ProcessID.log" &&
$dir _model"/check _status.sh" "$Folder" "$stepeg" > "$Folder""/""$stepeg""_Monitor.log" &&
$directory"/ws_client.sh" processPaths "$appName" "$step2" "$layers" "$genPath_01" > "$appLogFolder""/""$stepeg2""_ProcessID.log" &&
$dir_model"/check _status.sh" "$Folder" "$stepeg2" > "$Folder""/""$stepeg2""_Monitor.log" &
wait
 if (( ++i % 2 == 0))
then
echo "Waiting..."
wait
fi
```